# How do I see the details of a ScribeJava network error in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, scribe

This is the error that I am currently receiving when I try to get my request tokens from Twitter:

`org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.`

I've tested if I am on the UI thread or other threads (not on the UI thread). The current error is nondescript - what is the best/fastest way for me to figure out why remote connection is not working.

This was working a few hours ago, but when I went home it stopped getting connected.

Answer (score 0):

current version of ScribeJava has additionally an url in such error statements.
https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/04195020558ea17ba1c271b85ef40977055942c8/scribejava-core/src/main/java/com/github/scribejava/core/model/OAuthRequest.java#L39

stacktrace here as well

You can download sources and debug as well. Or enhance ScribeJava even more by creating new Pull Request.